# ¿En qué zonas se usa "A lo de mi abuela" o "Donde mi abuela" para referirse a "Voy a la casa de mi abuela"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

Quiero decir: "Voy a la casa de mi abuela".

- En Argentina siempre he escuchado: "Voy a lo de mi abuela".
- En Chile, parece que utilizan: "Voy donde mi abuela".

¿Qué suelen decir en otros paises? ¿Usan una expresión diferente? ¿O siempre tienen que decir "a la casa de" o "donde vive"? ¿Puedo usar las dos formas en un texto un poco más formal?

Comment: Vas a encontrar también "Voy a casa de ..." , "Voy a la casa de ...", "Voy lo de ..." (a mí me suena muy mal), "Voy de mi abuela", y probablemente muchas mas

Comment: Muchas formas para decirlo :) Pero las dos formas que dí, están reconocidas en otras partes que los paises mencionados?

Comment: No es solo una cuestión de "países". En este tipo de expresiones hay variaciones entre localidades, niveles educativos y grupos de pertenencia "social"

Comment: Gracias a todos por su respuestas! Me ayudaron todos! Ahora si alguien viene de Paraguay, Bolivia o Peru dejen me un comentario sobre como lo dicen ahi, para ver que tan extenso es hacia el norte

Comment: En Venezuela es muy común oír "voy donde la abuela" o "voy donde mi abuela". O por lo menos era muy común...ya llevo casi 20 años fuera del país... =P

Comment: Soy argentino y del sur, donde hay gran inmigración e influencia chilena. Efectivamente, lo que yo veo como forma correcta, es "voy a lo de mi abuela". Pero en mi región mucha gente usa "voy donde mi abuela", forma que yo siento que denota un poco de cultura de barrios pobres, y ahora me doy cuenta, influencia chilena.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En México se utiliza decir coloquialmente: "Voy a casa de mi abuela", removiendo el artículo, o incluso simplemente "Voy con mi abuela", infiriendo que la persona va a su casa...

Si el uso que se busca es mucho más formal, se puede intercambiar el verbo: Me dirijo a la casa de mi abuela.

Comment: Y en el campo he oído "Voy oncá mi abuela" (=voy a la casa está mi abuela).

Answer (score 4):

En España normalmente se usaría

> Voy a casa de mi abuela.

Como menciona Gabriel G. Ésta sería la forma más formal, en mi opinión.

Si se está comentando a miembros de la familia o muy allegados se puede usar:

> Voy a casa de abuela << (se usa "abuela" como si fuera un nombre propio)

En algunas partes del sur de España (Andalucía) se suele usar una expresión apocopada:

> Voy "anca" mi abuela. << "*Anca*" = "*a casa*" (se omite la preposición "de").

Comment: +1 por _anca_, aunque es terriblemente coloquial. Yo lo he oido en Extremadura y en Salamanca también. A veces se dice _ancá_.

Comment: Es coloquial en castellano pero perfectamente regular en asturleonés: voi an ca mio güela (*an* quiere decir *a en*, y el *de* se elide muchas veces después de vocales), cosa que seguramente influyó el uso en las tierras extremeñas y leonesas

Comment: en andalucia he oído hasta "acá mi abuela", o tal vez es "a ca mi abuela". el caso es que es sin la *n* de "anca mi abuela"

Answer (score 2):

Por lo visto en México hay una gran variedad de maneras de decirlo.

La forma más generalizada sería **"Voy con mi abuela"** o **"Voy a casa de mi abuela"**, pero también he escuchado (dejando de lado si es correcto o no por la academia):

**"Voy a con mi abuela"**, con doble preposición, no es muy común.

**"Voy a lo de mi abuela"**, **"Voy a lo de Pepe"** en Nayarit y Jalisco, similar que en Argentina.

**"Voy enque mi abuela"**, **"Voy enque la Juana"**, en Sonora y otras partes del norte de México, que imagino deriva del regionalismo "ancá mi abuela" de Andalucía, España (como el origen de la gran parte de inmigrantes europeos en esta zona), y con artículo acompañando al propietario de la casa, similar al Catalán.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

En el norte de México especialmente en Monterrey, he escuchado que dicen "Voy anca abuelita" además los mexicanos usamos mucho el diminutivo especialmente si se refiere a la abuela, decir ABUELA suena muy tosco para muchos mexicanos y se opta por "abuelita" que es con más cariño, la primera vez que fui a Miami y escuche a mis amigos cubanos decir abuela me parecía como con falta de respeto pero ya me acostumbré a oírlo de esa manera.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Añado esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Edita libremente para incluir la versión de tu país o región.</sub>

---

### Argentina

> Voy a lo de mi abuela.

### Chile

> Voy donde mi abuela.

### España

> Voy a casa de mi abuela.
>   Voy a casa de abuela.

#### España - Andalucía

> Voy "ancá" mi abuela. (No muy común.)

#### España - Galicia

> Voy a la de mi abuela.

### México

> Voy a casa de mi abuela.
>   Voy con mi abuela.

No muy común:

> Voy a con mi abuela.

#### México - Nayarit y Jalisco

> Voy a lo de mi abuela.

#### México - Sonora

> Voy enque mi abuela.

#### México norte (especialmente Monterrey)

> Voy "ancá" mi abuela.

### Uruguay

> Voy a lo de mi abuela.

### Venezuela

> Voy donde mi abuela.
>   Voy a que mi abuela.

Comment: En México la expresión más corta sería "Voy con mi abuela"

Comment: Así es, en Chile no se usa el "voy a lo de mi abuela", de hecho cuando lo escuché a una amiga argentina, no lo entendía, y me explicó que decir: "a lo de..." es equivalente a decir: "a la casa de". .

Comment: En Uruguay se dice "voy a lo de mi abuela" como resumen de "voy a la casa de mi abuela." Es raro decirlo sin "a la".

Comment: En Venezuela es muy común oír "voy donde la abuela" o "voy donde mi abuela". O por lo menos era muy común...ya llevo casi 20 años fuera del país... =P

Comment: En Galicia usamos "Voy a la de mi abuela", donde "la" supongo que simplemente es un pronombre que se refiere a "la casa". ¿Nadie más utiliza esta fórmula? Es que no sé si es excesivamente común o excesivamente particular... Si es un regionalismo, lo añado al post ;)

Comment: @Alicia añade libremente, es wiki (bueno, no era, me despisté, ahora mismo lo convierto :P). Lo he consultado a una amiga gallega y me dice que ella también lo usa