# Ir de alguien / Ir a lo de alguien

Tags: modismos, argentina, uruguay

Entre desconocidos que nos cruzamos en Twitter surgió la pregunta de si nos sonaba (bien o mal) la expresión “ir de alguien”, que funciona igual que “ir a lo de alguien”, ambas con el significado de “ir a la casa de alguien”.

> Mañana voy [a lo] de mis viejos.
>   Estoy por ir [a lo] de un amigo, ¿me acompañás?
>   Fui [a lo] del zapatero; todavía no terminó con mis botas.

A partir de una rápida búsqueda concluyo que “ir a lo de alguien” es por lo menos un modismo rioplatense y muy posiblemente aparezca en algunos otros dialectos; “ir de alguien”, no obstante, le resulta extraño a unos cuantos argentinos, aunque lo hayan oído (algunos lo asocian con el habla coloquial del interior de la provincia de Buenos Aires o del litoral). La dispersión de los interlocutores me impide hacer una encuesta, por supuesto. Algunos indican que se trata de un italianismo, otros apuntan a calcos del francés o del gallego, en fin: un festival de folklore.

Mis preguntas:

1. ¿Emplean ustedes estas expresiones (*ir a lo de* / *ir de*), o al menos una de ellas?
2. ¿Saben ustedes de dónde provienen?

Comment: Relacionado, falta el *ir de* http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/a-lo-de-mi-abuela-donde-mi-abuela

Comment: En España nunca lo oí. Solemos decir _Ir donde alguien_ en habla bastante coloquial.

Comment: Aquí en La Plata, Buenos Aires, es sumamente común decir 'voy de {alguien}' como abreviación de 'voy a lo de {alguien}'. Nunca se utiliza el 'donde', como en Chile, Colombia o Mexico. Así que probablemente sea un modismo rioplatense como indican, con fuerte influencia de la migración italiana, que aquí es mayoría.

Answer (score 3):

Debo decir que para mí "lo de X (alguien)" es correcto para referirse al lugar donde vive o trabaja alguien. Aquí he encontrado una referencia en una gramática. No será la NGLE, pero al menos da cuenta del fenómeno (es una gramática publicada en España en 2005): [Uso de "en lo de"](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=CfBPcmsqqe8C&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=%22en%20lo%20de%22%20gramatica&source=bl&ots=gPErAjVRyr&sig=MRVxy9xKjeR8LWhsYfcHGDmDmsk&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnqOnO59nSAhVEvJAKHYieB3kQ6AEIJzAD#v=onepage&q=%22en%20lo%20de%22%20gramatica&f=false)

En caso que no puedan abrir el enlace, aquí pueden ver la imagen:

[image: en lo de]

Como argentino, oigo todo el tiempo "ir de alguien" o "estar de alguien", que, aunque no gramaticales, sin duda son, en el habla coloquial, formas apocopadas del correcto "ir **a lo de** alguien" o "estar **en lo de** alguien".

En cuanto al uso de "donde", lo encuentro incorrecto así como Pablo Baeza encuentra "en/a lo de" incorrecto. En un Diccionario de Dudas Gramaticales en Internet, tal vez argentino, encuentro esto:

[image: Donde]

En fin, como reza el dicho, "cada maestro con su librito".

Comment: Solo por comentar. Es posible que ese uso de "de alguien" sea un calco sintáctico del italiano *da qualcuno*, que se emplea efectivamente con ese sentido.

Comment: @Paco Ese origen italiano fue uno de los sugeridos informalmente en la conversación que tuve. Lo considero probable ya que *ir de alguien* es usado en la zona central de Argentina donde hubo mayor inmigración italiana.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que el empleo de "Voy de alguien" se ha filtrado desde el italiano, y por eso es tan usual en el lenguaje rioplatense.  En italiano "voy a lo de mis padres" se dice "vado dai miei genitori".

Answer (score 1):

En Chile, Colombia, España y Perú, suena muy mal al oído esa sintaxis que planteas. Lo que se usa más formalmente en los mencionados lugares es: ir donde (...).

Al decir "Estoy por ir de un amigo", está completamente mal. El verbo toma una ambivalencia que induce a la confusión. Ir de un amigo, quiere decir la partida de éste, dicho de forma infinitivo, y si antepones una estructura en primera persona singular, pierde total coherencia.

algunos ejemplos. 
Estoy por ir donde un amigo. 
Vamos a la casa de Pedro / Vamos donde Pedro. 
Vamos a la plaza. 
Vamos a lo de la plaza (entendido que van a la actividad de la plaza, no precisamente a la locación física).

Lo correcto siempre será armar una estructura completa:
Estoy por ir a la casa de un amigo.
Vamos a la actividad de la plaza. 
Vamos a la fiesta en (la) casa de Pedro.

Ahora bien, en Twitter, se dan ciertas licencias de contracción extrema del lenguaje, por el formato en que se da el espacio de escritura.

Espero te ayude mi humilde sugerencia. 
Saludos.

Comment: La pregunta fue hecha en Twitter, pero la expresión no es una licencia motivada por el medio. Mucha gente la usa en el discurso hablado (incluyéndome) y sin mayor problema en cuanto a ser entendidos. Mi pregunta no apunta a si es una expresión correcta o no, sino a conocer su origen y distribución.

Comment: El español es una gran lengua, que merece un mínimo de ejercicio en su buena praxis. Por la estructura que preguntas y su origen, claramente es del ámbito local específico de alguna región, por lo que no es preponderante ni prominente. Ergo, solo alguien de alguna región que use esa expresión mal habida, podría responder esa duda con certeza en la locación.